Firebase functions onValueCreated database trigger not working
I wrote below trigger
exports.onNewGameRequest = onValueCreated(
{ref: "/game_requests/{uid}", region: "europe-west1"},
async (event) => {
  // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
  const original = event.data.val();
  console.log("onNewGameRequest", event.params.pushId, original);
  // make matches
  return await makeMatches();
},);

It never gets executed when I insert a new entry to "game_requests" collection.
Any ideas why?

You tagged this with "google-cloud-firestore", but your code shows a trigger for a different database product, Firebase Realtime Database.  They are definitely not the same and don't work much the same.  Which are you actually working with?  Please update your question to be clear.

My guess is that this mixup is precisely the reason it doesn't work, so I'd recommend posting that as an answer @DougStevenson.

I've tried to use const {onValueCreated} = require("firebase-functions/v2/database"), version ^6.1.0, but without success. The only way that I could get the desirable behavior was using an "Eventarc trigger" (https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/run/route-trigger-firebase-realtime-database).
